# JRE fatal error while using OpenNI java wrapper

Tags: java-native-interface, java, openni

Im trying to record a depth map to an .oni file with OpenNI using the java wrapper. This is my current code:

```
Context context = new Context();

DepthGenerator depth = DepthGenerator.create(context);

Recorder recorder = Recorder.create(context, null); //null gives .oni.

recorder.addNodeToRecording(depth);

context.startGeneratingAll();

while(true){
    context.waitAnyUpdateAll();
    recorder.Record();
}
```

When Im running it, this error is produced:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005b7bd579, pid=8048, tid=6784

JRE version: 7.0-b147
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [jvm.dll+0xed579]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
Recorder recorder = Recorder.create(context, "oni");
```

I needed to specify the file format. Passing in a null value was not the best idea obviously.